# knockout.js binding different texts for <select> and <option>

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, knockout.js

Is it possible in some way to have my selection(the text that appears in the  element) separately from my options text so that i can trim it and return in better looking way.

For example in this [Jsbin](http://jsbin.com/iPuCIni/1/edit)  i want to trim the selected item and add three dots at the end when it is shown as a selected element(already tried with CSS but I gave up because of the browser differences)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a wrapper object with computed that trims your text:

```
var ItemModel = function(value){
  var self = this;

  self.value = ko.observable(value);
  self.text = ko.computed(function(){
    val = self.value();
    if (val.length > 15){
      return val.substring(0, 15) + "...";
    }
    return val;
  });
};
```

Add use it instead of plain js object:

```
self.listOptions = ko.observableArray([
    new ItemModel('Neque porro quisquam est qui dolorem ipsum quia dolor sit amet, consectetur, adipisci'),
    new ItemModel('Neque porro quisquam est qui dolorem ipsum'),
    new ItemModel('Proin ultrices, tellus id placerat congue, neque justo commodo purus, et pulvinar massa')
]);
```

Also you need to modify your binding to use different properties for `value` and `text`:

```
<select data-bind="foreach: listOptions, value: selectedValue, attr: {title : selectedValue}" >
  <option data-bind="text: text, value: value"></option>
</select>
```

Here is working jsbin:
http://jsbin.com/oFIdAXO/3/edit

Comment: Thanks for your answer, it really gave me some great ideas but I am trying to keep the options text untouched and to change only the text in the select element. Thank you in advance.